# How do i resolve Hibernate.createBlob() method error at compilation Spring3 Hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have an issue while compiling my DocumentManager application in eclipse. it is not getting Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream()) method and giving "The method createBlob(InputStream) is undefined for the type Hibernate". I am using Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 with Maven. Please suggest me some solution. Code below... Thanks

```
package com.ecom.data.access.controller;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.sql.Blob;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.ecom.data.access.dao.DocumentDAO;
    import com.ecom.data.access.model.Document;

    import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
    import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    @Controller
    public class DocumentController {

        @Autowired
        private DocumentDAO documentDao;

        @RequestMapping("/index")
        public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
            try {
                map.put("document", new Document());
                map.put("documentList", documentDao.list());
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "documents";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(
                @ModelAttribute("document") Document document,
                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {


            System.out.println("Name:" + document.getName());
            System.out.println("Desc:" + document.getDescription());
            System.out.println("File:" + file.getName());
            System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

            try {
                Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

                document.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
                document.setContent(blob);
                document.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                documentDao.save(document);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "redirect:/index.html";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/download/{documentId}")
        public String download(@PathVariable("documentId")
                Integer documentId, HttpServletResponse response) {

            Document doc = documentDao.get(documentId);
            try {
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +doc.getFilename()+ "\"");
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType(doc.getContentType());
                IOUtils.copy(doc.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @RequestMapping("/remove/{documentId}")
        public String remove(@PathVariable("documentId")
                Integer documentId) {

            documentDao.remove(documentId);

            return "redirect:/index.html";
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is correct, there is no `Hibernate.createBlob` method. Why do you think that such a method exists?

Comment: It existed in Hibernate 3, though with not quite that signature.

Answer (score 6):

The method Hibernate.createBlob() is depreciated, you can use Hibernate.getLobCreator(sessionfactory.getCurrentSession()).createBlob() instead

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't resolve that method, as it doesn't exist.

In Hibernate 3, there was a method *almost* like what you're calling, but it had an additional integer argument specifying the size.

That method still exists in Hibernate 4, but in a different place.  You probably want to call the [Hibernate.getLobCreator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Hibernate.html#getLobCreator%28org.hibernate.Session%29) method and then use the [createBlob](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/LobCreator.html#createBlob%28java.io.InputStream,%20long%29) method on that.